# Notify command that CanExecuteChanged from other command

Tags: c#

I have following ViewModel:

```
public ICommand AddNewFilm { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddNewFilmWindow { get; set; }
    public ICommand CancelNewFilm { get; set; }
    public ICommand ShowFilm { get; set; }
    public ICommand FilterFilm { get; set; }
    public ICommand OrderFilm { get; set; }
    public ICommand SearchFilm { get; set; }

    public Repository<SpravaFilmuDbContext, FilmModel> FilmService { get; set; }

    public FilmViewModel()
    {
        InitData();
        InitCommands();
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        this.Name = "Films";
        this.Service = new FilmService();
        base.LoadData();
        this.NewItem = null;
        this.ShowItem = null;
    }

    private void InitCommands()
    {
        this.AddNewFilm = new AddNewFilmCommand(this);
        this.AddNewFilmWindow = new AddNewFilmWindowCommand(this);
        this.CancelNewFilm = new CancelNewFilmCommand(this);
        this.ShowFilm = new ShowFilmCommand(this);
        this.FilterFilm = new FilterFilmCommand(this);
        this.OrderFilm = new OrderFilmCommand(this);
        this.SearchFilm = new SearchFilmCommand(this);
    }
```

And in AddNewFilmWindow I have CanExecute like this:

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.ViewModel.NewItem == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The NewItem is set back to null when user use CancelNewFilm command.

Now the problem: I would like to notify AddNewFilmWindow after CancelNewFilm is used that it can be executed again. I can't put this into CancelNewFilmCommand because I don't have reference to the AddNewFilmWindow, right? Have no idea how to solve this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the `ViewModel` to your `ICommand` you can clear the `NewItem` property within the `CancelNewFilmCommand`.

By reference the `NewItem` property should be null within the `CanExecute` override of `AddNewFilmWindow`.

Comment: When I tried debuging, after I use button that triggers execute of CancelNewFilmCommand it won't trigger CanExecute  in AddNewFilmWindow :/ I even't tried to force update all items with CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); but not doing anythin either.